# Need to quickly update Django model with difference between two other models

Tags: python, django

I'm populating my database from an API that provides year-to-date stats, and I'll be pulling from this API multiple times a day. Using the year-to-date stats, I need to generate monthly and weekly stats. I'm currently trying to do this by subtracting the stats at the start of the month from the stats at the end of the month and saving it in a separate model, but the process is taking far too long and I need it to go faster.

My models look something like this :

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now) # Date pulled from API
    customer_id = models.IntegerField(default=0) # Simplified for this example
    a = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    b = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    c = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    d = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Leaderboard(models.Model):
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="YEARLY") # "MONTHLY", "WEEKLY"
    customer_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    start_stats = models.ForeignKey(Stats, related_name="start_stats") # Stats from the start of the Year/Month/Week
    end_stats = models.ForeignKey(Stats, related_name="end_stats") # Stats from the end of the Year/Month/Week
    needs_update = models.BooleanField(default=False) # set to True only if the end_stats changed (likely when a new pull happened)
    a = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    b = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    c = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    d = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    e = models.IntegerField(default=0) # A value computed based on a-d, used to sort Leaderboards
```

I thought I was going to be home free using `Leaderboard.objects.filter(needs_update=True).update(a=F("end_stats__a")-F("start_stats__a"), ...)`, but that gave me an error *"Joined field references are not permitted in this query"*.

I'm currently iterating over the QuerySet `Leaderboard.objects.filter(needs_update=True)`, doing the subtraction operations, and saving (all with `@transaction.atomic`), but ~380,000 test records processed this way took just over an hour, so I suspect that this way is going to be too slow for what I need.

---

I'm OK with changing how I store the data if a different format would help this Leaderboard update go faster (maybe do the subtraction when pulling in the data and saving daily deltas instead?), but I feel like I keep rushing towards whatever comes to mind without any idea of what I *should* be doing in this situation. Any feedback at this point would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar kind of issue where I was iterating over lots of data and doing calculations on them. In the end I  had to use threading and queues to make the wait time more bearable.

Comment: why not use the rdbms engine for what it's good at and use a stored procedure?  without selects preferably, all set-based insert/updates , sprinkle in some temp tables as required. in a previous job, we had strong instructions not to use select-based code on large data sets. that was after some bozo wrote a massive if/then/else construct to loop on a table with up to 5-10M rows easy (not in his test db though).  blew up on first customer site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering, I think I've got a method that will work for this situation. My test sample is smaller than before (84,600 records), but it completes in 8 seconds - about 10,575 records per second (compared to the roughly 6,300 records per second of my earlier tests).

There's probably a way to refine this even more, but here's what I'm doing:

```
    from django.db.models import F, Subquery, OuterRef

    # Get the latest versions of the stats
    Leaderboard.objects.filter(needs_update=True).update(
        a=Subquery(Stats.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('end_stats')).values('a')[:1]),
        b=Subquery(Stats.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('end_stats')).values('b')[:1]),
        c=Subquery(Stats.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('end_stats')).values('c')[:1]),
        d=Subquery(Stats.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('end_stats')).values('d')[:1])
    )

    # Subtract the earliest versions of the stats
    Leaderboard.objects.filter(needs_update=True).update(
        a=F('a') - Subquery(Stats.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('start_stats')).values('a')[:1]),
        b=F('b') - Subquery(Stats.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('start_stats')).values('b')[:1]),
        c=F('c') - Subquery(Stats.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('start_stats')).values('c')[:1]),
        d=F('d') - Subquery(Stats.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('start_stats')).values('d')[:1])
    )

    # Calculate stats that require earlier stats.
    Leaderboard.objects.filter(needs_update=True).update(
        e=F('a') + F('b') * F('c') / F('d'),
        needs_update=False
    )
```

I feel like there should be a way to only use one `Subquery` per update, which should improve the speed even more.